# "I decided just to go away", "I decided to just go away", "I just decided to go away"?

Tags: adverb-position

What I mean is:

```
I decide this: just going away.
```

Does any of the sentences below convey that sense in a gramatically correct way?

```
I decided just to go away.
I decided to just go away.
I just decided to go away.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that in your stated meaning you're using "just" to mean

> really; absolutely (used for emphasis).

In which case the first or second ones are both grammatically correct and the best fit, the first being the best in my opinion as it avoids a split infinitive (but some people aren't too bothered about that anyway).

The third one can be used to convey that meaning, but may be confused for using just with the meaning

> very recently; in the immediate past.

Which would change the meaning to "I decided at this exact moment in time to go away" which isn't what you wanted.

Even ignoring that potential confusion it's still not quite the same because with this one "to go away" is what you decided to do (less emphasis) and you're emphasising that you decided something rather than what the decision was.